# How to find the first input or select or radiobutton or checkbox in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML with DIV's containing all possible input types i.e. text, select, radio btn or checkbox.

how can i write jQuery selector which will always select the first input element in a type

```
<div id="testID">

<input id="txt" type="text">
<input id ="rdbtn" type="radio">
<input id="chkbox" type="checkbox">

<select id="slt">
<option value=1>Good Morning</option>
<option value=2>Hello</option>
<option value=3>Hi</option>
</select>


</div>
```

So the DIV's DOM structure can change.

I have tried

```
jQuery('#testID select').first()
```

or

```
jQuery('#testID input ').first()
```

But how can i write a selector which will select the first input type irrespective of changing DOM structure

Comment: Try `$('#testID').find(':input')[0]`

Comment: wait, do you mean get the first input **or** select element?

Comment: @AmmarCSE, I meant whatever is the first element, which could be either an input / select/radio button

Comment: @RayonDabre, You made it look so simple !!! your suggestion seems to working , i will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: In that case, do like @RayonDabre suggested

Comment: `select` will not be an `input` otherwise you can use @RayonDabre's comment as answer..

Comment: @RayonDabre, can i exclude hidden fields by adding $('#testID').find(':input :visible')[0]

Comment: @CSharped, yes but remove the space. Do it like `$('#testID').find(':input:visible')[0]`

Comment: @CSharped, Answer will be NO. But `$('#testID').find(':input:not([type=hidden])')[0]` might help!

Comment: @RayonDabre, this suggests otherwise. https://jsfiddle.net/fvcu0w1y/ Therefore, it is possible

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, i tried this $('#testID').find(':input').not("hidden")[0]

Comment: @AmmarCSE, I thought he was asking using this `$('#testID').find(':input')[0]` syntax. You are right! ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre, you should answer this question so that future readers can benefit

Answer (score 4):

To get the first `input` field from the specify container, one needs to [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) as the `:input` selector basically selects all form controls. Just in case you wants to avoid hidden fields, you can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. which will filter the elements as per the query.

Refer this example:

```js
var firstInput = $('#testID').find(':input')[0];
console.log(firstInput);

var firstNonHiddenInput = $('#testID').find(':input:not([type=hidden])')[0];
console.log(firstNonHiddenInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testID">
  <input id="txt_hidden" type="hidden">
  <input id="txt" type="text">
  <input id="rdbtn" type="radio">
  <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox">

  <select id="slt">
    <option value=1>Good Morning</option>
    <option value=2>Hello</option>
    <option value=3>Hi</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Good one! So, the selector would be `:input:not(:hidden):first`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
jQuery('#testID input[type=text]:eq(0)')
jQuery('#testID select:eq(0)')
```